# window.screenY in a dual screen environment

Tags: javascript, multiple-monitors

I am trying to determine how the value for window.screenY is derived on the second monitor in a windows 8.0 dual screen environment and whether or not it can be programmatically recalculated (using javascript) to return the same outcome as it would in a single screen environment.

My test setup is a laptop with resolution 1366 x 768 running as the primary display and
an attached monitor with resolution 1920 x 1080 running as the second display.

Assuming a maximised browser at 100% zoom I would expect window.screenY equal to 0 (or a negative value equal to the chrome e.g. -8):

IE10         -8
FF           -8
chrome        0
opera         0

On the second monitor I am getting:

IE10        -203
FF          -203
chrome      -195
opera       -195

A difference of -195 in each instance.

Presumably this difference has some relationship to the difference in the respective display heights?

768 – 1080 = -312

-312 / 2 = -156

With regard to screen.height on the second display:

IE returns the height of the primary display (768).
The other browsers return that of the second display (1080).
So in either instance there is only information about one of the displays.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In most multi-monitor setups, you can choose the relative position of the two displays (this is intended to match your physical setup). The offset you notice is probably related to this: try changing the relative position of the two screens in the Windows "Display" Control Pannel and see how it affects the result.

Comment: thanks jcaron, my displays in the example I gave match the physical set up. If I swap them round so that the larger display is position 1, then the difference of -195 I described in my question becomes -172. Maybe by co-incidence but -156 -8 -8 = -172.

Comment: I did not mean to swap them around (though that indeed has an influence), but move them. You can "slide" one screen up or down relative to the other for instance, and I'm pretty sure that would change the results. Not sure what the default relative position is, it probably depends on the size of the screens, and possibly their advertised resolution (in dpi)

Comment: Not that you can also have one screen "below" the other. And I'm pretty sure that with 3 or 4 monitors you can have a lot of fun.

Comment: Okay thanks, but from the perspective of scripting with window.screenY, perhaps to position something on a page, in a multi monitor set up you can't really make much sense of it then?

Comment: Not much, no. I believe you can (in some OS/browser combinations) find the whole screen size (that "contains" all of the screens, but may have non-visible sections), and from that try to detect that there's a multiple-screen setup (if the ratio is radically different from the usual 4/3 to 16/9), and (again on some OS/browser combinations) try to guess on which screen you are, but that's about it. What's your actual goal here?

Comment: In this instance, I'm trying to center a pop up on the window where the user requests it. With multiple screens this seems near impossible, I would settle for centered on the parents screen, rather than window, but even this seems unlikely.

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this thread, I have now had time to slide the relative positions about, and you are correct that the offset of -195 I mentioned in my question can be explained by this.